# W3schools automatic slideshow is not showing up, what did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't make the w3schools automatic slideshow to show up or work.

I have done it in the past but as soon as I add the css it just dissapears, deleting to my slide `display: none` makes the pictures show up but one beneath another instead of as a slideshow.

It is being placed under four columns, `div` seems to be placing fine when inspecting.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="6.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="7.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="8.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="9.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough dots, so javascript will throw an error and stop the slideshow.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer made the dots show up, which is good, but still have no slideshow above. So helpful but not solving my problem.

Comment: I don't get what is your problem. Can you explain it?

Comment: Hi, so it was my slideshow not showing up at all, not displaying the pictures. I have finally solved this issue by making my javascript going all the way under all elements of my body. So I solved this issue, but don't know why having it at the top of my body was the problem since I have read that it can go at the top or bottom and it was only a thing of loading time. I will now make an external javascript so I won't have any future issues related to that. Thank you so much for your time and if you have any idea why the problem occured, happy to learn.

Comment: Oh, I automatically put it at the end of the body. If you want to put it at the top just use [defer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)